# WebSphere application server scheduler or java scheduler for insert

Tags: java, websphere-8

I am working on an application which is deployed on web-sphere application server 8.0. This application insert record in one table and uses the data-source by jndi lookup.

I need to create a batch job which will read data from the above table and will insert into some other table continuously on a fixed interval of time. It will be deployed on the same WAS server and use the same jndi lookup for data source.

I read on internet that  web-sphere application server scheduling is an option and is done using EJB and session beans.

I also read about jdk's ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. I can create a war having ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor implementation and deploy it on the WAS for this.

I tried to find the difference between these two in terms of usage, complexity, performance and maintainability but could not.

**Please help me in deciding which approach will be better for creating the scheduler for insert batch jobs and why. And in case if WAS scheduler is better then please provide me link to create and deploy the same.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some major differences between WAS Scheduler and Java SE ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is that WAS Scheduler is transactional (task execution can roll back or commit), persistent (tasks are stored in a database), and can coordinate across members of a cluster (such that tasks can be scheduled from any member but only run on one member).  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is much lighter weight approach because it doesn't have any of these capabilities and does all of its scheduling within a single JVM. Task executions neither roll back nor retry and are not kept externally in a database in case the server goes down.  It should be noted that WebSphere Application Server also has CommonJ TimerManager (and AlarmManager via WorkManager) which are more similar to what you get with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor if that is what you want. In that case, the application server still manages the threads and ensures that context of the scheduling thread is available on the thread of execution. Hope this helps with your decision.

Comment: I should also mention the option of combining the two. Use WAS Scheduler to get the behavior of having your scheduled task persist across server restarts, and when it runs, have it submit a WorkManager task to do the real work on a separate thread (apart from the Scheduler transaction) and return immediately from the Scheduler task. Then if your job is long running, it won't hit transaction timeouts and you will be free to start and commit your own transactions within the job, but you do have a risk, if it runs a sufficiently long time, that execution could overlap the start of the next one.